# Applescript: Open current Safari tab in Chrome (Troubleshoot of working script)

Tags: safari, applescript, google-chrome, alfred

So, I decided a while ago to run a Flash-free install of Safari. It's been really great, Safari seems much more stable overall and I barely miss it.

But every once in a while I stumble upon a site that requires flash (mostly YouTube videos, which I thought wouldn't be a problem given that Google was supposed to be switching everything over to HTML5), so for those cases I have an Appescript that runs when triggered through an Alfred Workflow (with a hotkey). The script is as such:

```
tell application "Safari"

    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1

end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"

    if windows ≠ {} then
        make new tab at the end of window 1 with properties {URL:theURL}
    else
        make new window
        set URL of active tab to theURL
    end if
    activate

end tell

tell application "Safari"

    close current tab of window 1

end tell
```

This usually runs perfectly, but I run into a weird problem whenever Chrome doesn't have an open window in the background. In these cases, Chrome will open a new (blank) window, and the script will stop right there. The third Tell statement,

```
 tell application "Safari"

    close current tab of window 1

end tell
```

Will never run, leaving me with an open chrome window and an open safari window as well. It is only after I press the hotkey a second time, after the Chrome window is already open, that the Script will run it's course and open the page in chrome/close the tab in safari.

Any ideas? I'm really confused by the fact the third tell statement won't run at all. If the Chrome window opened up blank but the safari tab still closed I would guess it was a simple error in the if/else statement, but the fact that the script seems to terminate is really stumping me on this one.

Comment: You do know that Safari has a built in function for this, right? `Develop`->`Open Page With`->`Google Chrome`. You can assign hotkey for this action in system preferences

Comment: Yea, but this is actually part of a larger script that lets me do the same in both directions; Safari to Chrome and Chrome to Safari. Also, unlike the script the method you mention won't close the Safari window that's being opened in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because Safari and Chrome are running, doesn't mean that they have a window open. You can either test for open windows as Mark points out or simply issue the reopen command which opens a new window if one does not exist.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    -- insert your code 
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    -- insert your code 
end tell
```

EDIT

```
tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then return
    set theURL to URL of current tab of window 1
    close current tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    set URL of active tab of window 1 to theURL
end tell
```

Comment: A down vote without an explanation?

Comment: @adayzone, The "correct method is" to do what in relation to this question?

Comment: Hi Mark. The correct method of ensuring either Chrome or Safari has a window open to prevent the errors Carlos is getting, is to issue the reopen command. If it exists, it leaves the current window as is, if not, it opens a new one

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what to do with this :/. It may be obvious to someone with a bit more knowledge of Applescript, but to me personally this answer actually leaves me with more questions xD (on a side note, you've actually answered some of my questions before, so thanks for that!)

Comment: Ahhh I see now, you're referring specifically to the use of 'reopen'... I see where you're getting at.

Comment: @adayzdone, if you update your answer with a fuller explanation I am more than happy to vote it back up :-). You may also while you are at it take into account if Safari  reopens in Topsits: you may get an error because the is no URL

Comment: The edit works perfectly! It actually resolves a small annoyance with the other method, wherein if Chrome wasn't open at all it the new window would open with two tabs (a blank one and the one with the sent content). Thanks!

Comment: "if Safari reopens in Topsits: you may get an error because the is no URL". That is why I excluded it from my EDIT. I will add an explanation.

Comment: @Carlos I See what you mean about the two tabs. Thats is annoying. And I was going to suggest you accept adayzone's answer. But you already have :-)

Comment: @markhunte haha I'll be honest, I felt a bit bad about unaccepting yours! I would hope there was a way to recognize both apart from up votes, as they both have helped not only fix my problem but deepen my understanding of Applescript. But since there can only be one, and I did end up using adayzdone's version, I'll have to accept that one :) thanks again!

Comment: @Carlos don't feel bad. You did the right thing I feel in this case and I was going to suggest you do so. You can always vote mine up as being helpful if you found it so.

Comment: @markhunte I voted your answer down because of extra tab. Edit it and I will reverse.

Comment: @adayzdone I will leave it as it is. The question did not ask to eliminate the extra Tab. That was a bonus in you answer. And my answer was not addressing that. Feel free to up or down vote. It is all constructive. As was my originally down voting your answer which prompted you to give a fuller better answer that was not confusing and in the end was accepted because of that.

Comment: Oops. I must have assumed Carlos didn't want extra tab. Either way, can't reverse vote until an edit has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred may be shielding you from an error that occurs if Chrome is running  but does not have any windows open.

> Google Chrome got an error: Can’t set active tab to
>   "http.....".

Change the lines

```
  make new window
  set URL of active tab to theURL
```

to

```
set theWindow to make new window

set URL of active tab of theWindow to theURL
```

Comment: Ah, so it was an Alfred thing? I thought this might have been the case at first, but the whole last-tell-not-executing thing made me think it was something to do specifically. with Applescript. Your fixed worked a treat though! Thanks!